# Can a CronTrigger Job ID be used to determine if a job had been aborted or is invalid?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I have a function that gets called as part of reschedule logic in an Apex class that implements implements System.Schedulable.

```
@TestVisible private void reschedule(CronTrigger me, ISchedulable item, MySchedulableContext myCtx) {
        try {
            System.abortJob(me.Id);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug('Unable to abort the job');
        }
        String newTrigger = item.getNextTriggerString(myCtx);
        if (newTrigger != null && newTrigger.length() > 0) {
            try {
                System.schedule(me.CronJobDetail.Name+ '-' + System.currentTimeMillis(), newTrigger, this);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.debug('Unable to start the job');
            }

        }
    }
```

How would I know if the job I am about to abort is not already aborted or if the job I am about to start is not already started? Yes the try/catch will take care of errors however I would like to understand this better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [AsyncApexJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) Object to get the status of the job.

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Status, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, NumberOfErrors
FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE ID = :jobId
```

Then check the status if you would like. The available status are the following:

- Holding
- Queued
- Preparing
- Processing
- Aborted
- Completed
- Failed

So if Status is **Aborted** the job has been aborted already.